# After pandas loading the CSV file, the DataFrame has some wrong columns

Tags: pandas

I have a big CSV file that size more than 5G, so I tried to part of to load the file as below codes.

```
import pandas as pd

reader = pd.read_csv('/path/to/csv', chunksize=10000, error_bad_lines=True, iterator=True)

for chunk in reader:
  with open('/path/to/save', 'a') as chunk_file:
    chunk.to_csv(chunk_file)
```

I saw some warning like:

```
Skipping line 8245: expected 1728 fields, saw 1729
```

I thought the saved file would be without the dirty data, but the file still exists some wrong data columns.

I've set up the error_bad_lines, I don't know why that happened?

Comment: So the warning is telling you that there is something wrong with that line, did you check this?

Comment: You can set this flag ```error_bad_lines``` to false to drop bad lines as mentioned here. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Some field in that line has a comma `,`, so the line contains one more commas than the header.

Comment: I apologize for the question, I have a mistake about error_bad_lines=True, actually, that's a value of False. So that's why the strange.

Comment: Because that is a business project, so I can't paste all of the codes to here. thank you guys helping me, any concerns please tell me.